# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp({inx})\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

Can someone tell me why this integral gives zero:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp({inx})\mathrm dx$$

Where $n=1,2,3, \cdots $.

I am a bit confused since $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \exp({nx}) dx$ does not give zero.

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula $\exp(i\theta) = \cos \theta + i \sin\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\exp (inx) = \cos (nx) + i \sin (nx).$$

Comment: Ahh.. Of course. I totally forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the $i$ is an imaginary number:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{inx} \mathrm{dx}=\left.\frac{e^{inx}}{in}\right|_0^{2\pi}=\frac{1}{in}\left[e^{in2\pi}-e^{in0}\right]=\frac{1}{in}[1-1]=0$$

In the last step i used:
$e^{in2\pi}=1$ and $e^{in0}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $x \mapsto e^{inx}$ is $2\pi$ periodic, for $n=1,2,3, \cdots $, then you have 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}dx=\left. \frac{e^{inx}}{in}\right|_0^{2\pi}=\frac{e^{2i\pi n}-e^{0}}{in}=\frac{1-1}{in}=0.
$$